# Sorting a Table but Table header is broken

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, sorting

I am making a help section for my Minecraft server so players can see commands and their usage.
I have sorted them to make it make more sense when trying to find a command.

For some reason, it organises the table by Cmds but it put the table header at the bottom.
How would I make it skip over this?
There is also a blank entry for some reason.

```
<table id="cmdlist">
    <tr>
        <th>Command</th>
        <th><i style="color: rgb(0,255,255);">Tuple</i> Arguments</th>
        <th>Usage</th>
        <th>Server(s)</th>
        <th>Rank</th>
    </tr>
    <td>
    </td>
</table>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var Cmds,Args,Usage,Server,Rank;
    Cmds = ["/server","/msg","/r","/island,/is","/towny,/t","/nation,/n","/echest","/craft,/wb,/workbench","/tpa","/tpahere","/tpaccept"];
    Args = ["(servername)","(playname) (message)","(message)","(optional)","(optional)","(optional)","N/A","N/A","(playername)","(playername)","N/A"]
                Usage = ["Used to switch between the hub and gamemodes.",
                "Used to send a pm to a player.",
                "Sends a pm to the player you last sent/recieved a pm from.",
                "Without args opens gui. With args open a specific section.",
                "Without args displays town info. With args you can config your town.",
                "Without args displays nation info. With args you can config your nation.",
                "Open your enderchest via a command.",
                "Open a crafting table via a command.",
                "Sends a request to teleport to a player.",
                "Sends a request to teleport to a player to you.",
                "Accepts the last pending teleport request."
                ]
    Server = ["*","*","*","Skyblock","Towny","Towny","Towny/Skyblock","Towny/Skyblock","Towny/Skyblock","Towny/Skyblock","Towny/Skyblock"]
    Rank = ["*","*","*","* (Skyblock owner)","* (Town owner)","* (Town owner)","Donator,Donator+,DonatorPro,*Staff","Donator,Donator+,DonatorPro,*Staff","*","*","*"]
    Cmds.sort()
    Cmds.reverse()
    console.log(Cmds)
    var table = document.getElementById("cmdlist");
    var I;
    for (i = 1; i < Cmds.length; i++) {
        // Create an empty <tr> element and add it to the 1st position of the table:
        var row = table.insertRow(0);

        // Insert new cells (<td> elements) at the 1st and 2nd position of the "new" <tr> element:
        var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
        var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
        var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
        var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
        var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);

        // Add some text to the new cells:
        cell1.innerHTML = Cmds[i];
        cell2.innerHTML = Args[i];
        cell3.innerHTML = Usage[i];
        cell4.innerHTML = Server[i];
        cell5.innerHTML = Rank[i];
    }
</script>
```

Comment: There is an empty and unnecessary `td` in your table.  Usage array is too-indented.  Both don't effect anything (pretty sure about the `td`, definitely sure about indentation) - I've seen way worse... :)  It will help you to be consistent in re-understanding older codes you write as you progress.

Comment: It not like that in the editor, that is just from when I pasted it in. I have removed the td

Comment: `insertRow(index)` and `insertCell(index)` inserts *before* index, pushing everything further down/right(left if dir==rtl).  `0` prepends, and `-1` appends.  For "just adding a row at the end" use `-1`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In your code you are sorting **only the first column**.. is it ok?

```js
   const Cmds = [
       "/server",
       "/msg",
       "/r",
       "/island,/is",
       "/towny,/t",
       "/nation,/n",
       "/echest",
       "/craft,/wb,/workbench",
       "/tpa",
       "/tpahere",
       "/tpaccept"
   ];
   const Args = [
       "(servername)",
       "(playname) (message)",
       "(message)",
       "(optional)",
       "(optional)",
       "(optional)",
       "N/A",
       "N/A",
       "(playername)",
       "(playername)",
       "N/A"
   ];
   const Usage = [
       "Used to switch between the hub and gamemodes.",
       "Used to send a pm to a player.",
       "Sends a pm to the player you last sent/recieved a pm from.",
       "Without args opens gui. With args open a specific section.",
       "Without args displays town info. With args you can config your town.",
       "Without args displays nation info. With args you can config your nation.",
       "Open your enderchest via a command.",
       "Open a crafting table via a command.",
       "Sends a request to teleport to a player.",
       "Sends a request to teleport to a player to you.",
       "Accepts the last pending teleport request."
   ];
   const Server = [
       "*",
       "*",
       "*",
       "Skyblock",
       "Towny",
       "Towny",
       "Towny/Skyblock",
       "Towny/Skyblock",
       "Towny/Skyblock",
       "Towny/Skyblock",
       "Towny/Skyblock"
   ];
   const Rank = [
       "*",
       "*",
       "*",
       "* (Skyblock owner)",
       "* (Town owner)",
       "* (Town owner)",
       "Donator,Donator+,DonatorPro,*Staff",
       "Donator,Donator+,DonatorPro,*Staff",
       "*",
       "*",
       "*"
   ];

   Cmds.sort().reverse();
   var table = document.getElementById("cmdlist");
   for (let i = 0; i < Cmds.length; i++) {
       var row = table.insertRow(i+1);
       [
        Cmds,
        Args,
        Usage,
        Server,
        Rank
      ].forEach((column, index) => {
        row.insertCell(index).innerHTML = column[i]
      })
  }
```

```css
table, th, td {
  border: 1px dotted #cdcdcd;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background: #eee
}
tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #FFF
}

th {
  background-color: #000;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<table id="cmdlist">
    <tr>
        <th>Command</th>
        <th><i style="color: rgb(0,255,255);">Tuple</i> Arguments</th>
        <th>Usage</th>
        <th>Server(s)</th>
        <th>Rank</th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I removed the .reverse I put that in as it was sorting from z-a for some reason, the way you did it meant I didn't need to have that. Otherwise worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

`table.insertRow(0)` will add your row to the **beginning** of your table, pushing all the rows that come before it down (including your table header). Did you mean to do `table.insertRow(-1)`, which will add a row to the **end** of the table?

[insertRow reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement/insertRow)